# utilizar operador < con un label

Tags: c#, formularios, windows, operador, label

Buenas tarde alguno sabe como utilizar correctamente el operador <= en c#.
Tengo un label que se llama lblConsumo y necesito decirle que si es mayor o igual que 20 haga otra condición, pero no me deja hacer lblConsumo.Text >= 20

Comment: He probado las dos soluciones, pero con ninguna me funciona, siempre sale error.

Answer (score 1):

Es que `lblConsumo.Text` es un `String`, no es un entero. Para compararlo con un número, debes convertirlo en un valor numérico. Dependiendo de lo que sea puedes usar `int.parse(lblConsumo.Text) >= 20` si es un entero o bien `double.parse(lblConsumo.Text) >= 20` si es un número decimal.

Answer (score 0):

respuesta similar a la de Jaime Menendez, pero yo haria TryParse en vez de parse.
Es decir

```
double midoble = 0;
if (double.TryParse(lblConsumo.Text, midoble)){
//do something
}
```

entonces el valor te queda en midoble, pero mejor que todo esto es que inspecciones lblConsumo, el type y todo eso porque igual en alguna property tienes 20 en numero y te dejas de parsear